# Keyword search using python and sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a plugin to a game server that writes down changes made to a map.The database contains entries formatted like this - id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,matbefore INTEGER, matafter INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50), date DATE. I am trying to create a function that, when given a column name, an integer, string, or tuple of an integer or string, and a keyword, will find the selected entries. so far, this is the code that I have come to -

```
def readdb(self,keyword,column,returncolumn = "*"):
    self.memwrite
    if isinstance(keyword, int) or isinstance(keyword,str):
        entry = [keyword]
    qmarks = ("? OR " * len(entry))[:-4]
    statement = 'SELECT all {0} FROM main WHERE {1} is {2}'.format(returncolumn,column,qmarks)
    print(qmarks)
    self.memcursor.execute(statement, entry)
    return(self.memcursor.fetchall())
```

keyword is a keyword to search for, column is teh column to search in, and returncolumn is the column to return So I was wondering why this code always fetches no rows, EG - Returns None, no matter what I put for the function. It seems to work fine if I do these things in the console, but not if I wrap them in a function

Answer (score 1):

If `entry` is a list (like in yesterday's question) , it's not going to work.

```
>>> returncolumn = "*"
>>> column = "name"
>>> entry = ["Able", "Baker", "Charlie"]
>>> qmarks = ("? OR " * len(entry))[:-4]
>>> statement = 'SELECT all {0} FROM main WHERE {1} is {2}'.format(returncolumn,
column,qmarks)
>>> print statement
SELECT all * FROM main WHERE name is ? OR ? OR ?
```

and what SQLite will see is:

`SELECT all * FROM main WHERE name is 'Able' OR 'Baker' OR 'Charlie'`

which is not valid syntax because you need `=`, not `is`.

Even if you fix that then (using an integer query for example):

`SELECT all * FROM main WHERE id = 1 or 2 or 3`

you will get mysterious results because that means `WHERE ((id = 1) or 2) or 3)`, not what you think it does ... you need `WHERE id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3` or (reverting to yesterday's question) `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going.. again, sorry for that other post.. I was being stupid, not giving all the info

Answer (score 0):

```
def readdb(self,keyword,column,returncolumn = "*"):
    self.memwrite                                             # 1. 
    if isinstance(keyword, int) or isinstance(keyword,str):   # 2.
        entry = [keyword]                                     # 3.
    qmarks = ("? OR " * len(entry))[:-4]                      # 4.
    statement = 'SELECT all {0} FROM main WHERE {1} is {2}'.format(returncolumn,column,qmarks)
    print(qmarks)                                             # 5.
    self.memcursor.execute(statement, entry)
    return(self.memcursor.fetchall())
```

1. Not sure what this is supposed to
   do. Did you mean self.memwrite()?
2. Can be changed to `if
   isinstance(keyword, (int,str))`

   Or better yet, don't test the type.
   As you've written it, keyword can
   not be a unicode string. Why
   restrict like this? In this case I
   think it would be better to use
   a `try...except...` block to catch the subsequent
   error than to restrict type.
3. So at best `len(entry) = 1`. Notice
   also, its possible to never reach
   this line if keyword is not of type
   int or str. In that case, you would
   get an error on line (4) since entry
   would not be defined..
4. This could also be written as

   ```
   qmarks = ' OR '.join(['?']*len(entry))
   ```

   It avoids the need for the somewhat magic number 4 in  `("? OR " *1)[:-4]`.
5. What are you seeing here? If it was
   empty, that should have been a clue. Also it would be worth running
   `print(statement)` to get a full picture of what is being sent to `.execute()`.
6. Perhaps try

   ```
   statement = 'SELECT {0} FROM main WHERE {1} = ?'.format(
                returncolumn,column)
   ```

   In particular, the `is` should be changed to `=`.

Comment: Your points 1 and 5 were made to the OP yesterday when he asked much the same question (with two different versions of code, none of which were the code he actually ran) and then deleted his question. I predict a difficulty with getting any actual error messages or a print of the SQL statement being executed; believe it or not, these allegedly come out on a server's console and scroll off before they can be captured. Have fun ...

Comment: Answers to your questions : (1)- Yes, that was a typo, thanks for finding it, though it doesn't do anything relevant other than update the database with info from other(working) functions. What I get when I run this statement is None. I actually did have a print line, but I deleted it when posting the question.